# Get highest value from <td> in table by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the highest value in a table column by class? I have tried the following:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr><td class="speed">1.1</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="speed">3.1</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="speed">5.5</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="speed">2.0</td></tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery/Javascript**

```
function gethighestspeeds(){

    var speeds = $(".speed").map(function() {
       return parseFloat(this.text, 10);
    }).get();

    var highestspeed = Math.max.apply(Math, speeds);
    alert(highestspeed)
}
```

Also, how can I get all values if > than a certain number?

Comment: Would I use `.filter()` when getting values < or > a certain value?

Comment: `return parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.text` is undefined for the `td` element, you need to parse `parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);`

```js
function gethighestspeeds() {

  var speeds = $(".speed").map(function() {
    return parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);
  }).get();

  var highestspeed = Math.max.apply(Math, speeds);
  snippet.log('high: ' + highestspeed);

  var num = 2.3;
  var array = $(".speed").map(function() {
    var flt = parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);
    return flt > num ? flt : undefined;
  }).get();
  snippet.log('array: ' + array)

  //if you already have the speeds array
  var array2 = speeds.filter(function(val) {
    return num < val;
  });
  snippet.log('array2: ' + array)
}
gethighestspeeds();
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="speed">1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="speed">3.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="speed">5.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="speed">2.0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this........

```
var certainNumber=2.2; //Whatever you want to set

function gethighestspeeds(){

   var speeds = $(".speed").map(function() {
       return parseFloat(this.text, 10) > parseFloat(certainNumber);
       }).get();


}
```

Comment: It must be `this.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use : `$(this).text()` instead of `this.text` in your `map` function:

```
return parseFloat($(this).text(), 10);
```

Comment: I see my mistake now. Thanks so much!